# Query is not returning any values in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm a newbie here. Running the following select statement is not returning any values. Hive queries:

```
select name from patient where name = '[a-g]%';
select name from patient where name like '[a-g]%';
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this query run or it gave any exception? by syntax this query seems to be right. might be the patient table has no rows ?

Comment: Hi Satha, It doesn't give any error. It just returns 'Ok'. No the table has rows. I am able to retrieve values for the below query. select * from patient where name = 'a%';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select * from patient where lower(name) rlike '^[a-g].'  LIKE compares using SQL Regular expressions... RLIKE compares using Java Regular Expressions... you're sort of combining the two in your attempt above.